# snowflake.connector.errors.InterfaceError:252005: Failed to convert current row, cause:<class 'DeprecationWarning'> returned result with an error set

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "engine.py", line 90, in 
response_data = query_execution(sql_query, company_db)
File "engine.py", line 77, in query_execution
data =  cursor.fetchall()
File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 987, in fetchall
row = self.fetchone()
File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 953, in fetchone
return next(self._result)
File "src/snowflake/connector/arrow_result.pyx", line 125, in snowflake.connector.arrow_result.ArrowResult.**next**
File "src/snowflake/connector/arrow_iterator.pyx", line 224, in snowflake.connector.arrow_iterator.PyArrowIterator.**next**
File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 258, in errorhandler_wrapper
cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 188, in default_errorhandler
raise error_class(
snowflake.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 252005: Failed to convert current row, cause: <class 'DeprecationWarning'> returned a result with an error set

```
conn = hsdb.get_connect_string_red(company_db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query)
print("-----------------")
data =  cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
print(df)
```

'''

Comment: Please provide the context of the issue and how exactly it is showing up along with supporting data.

Comment: Are there any rows in the table you are querying with non UTF-8 characters? That can cause the issue if the data was loaded with *VALIDATE_UTF8=FALSE*.